# How to figure out if a modin dataframe is going to fit in RAM?

Tags: python, pandas, modin

Im learning how to work with large datasets, so im using modin.pandas.
I'm doing some aggregation, after which a 50GB dataset is hopefully going to become closer to 5GB in size - and now i need to check: if the df is small enough to fit in RAM, i want to cast it to pandas and enjoy a bug-free reliable library.
So, naturally, the question is: how to check it? `.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()` tells me how much the whole df uses, but i cant possibly know from that one number how much of it is in RAM, and how much is in swap - in other words, how much space do i need for casting the df to pandas. Are there other ways? Am i even right to assume that some partitions live in RAM while others - in swap? How to calculate how much data will flood the RAM when i call `._to_pandas()`? Is there a hidden `.__memory_usage_in_swap_that_needs_to_fit_in_ram()` of some sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am i even right to assume that some partitions live in RAM while others - in swap?

Modin doesn't specify whether data should be in RAM or swap.

On Ray, it [uses](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/blob/e7cb2e82f8b9c7a68f82abdd3b6011d661230b7e/modin/core/execution/ray/implementations/pandas_on_ray/partitioning/partition.py#L228) [`ray.put`](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/package-ref.html#ray-put) to store partitions. `ray.put` doesn't give any guarantees about where the data will go. Note that Ray spills data blocks to disk when they are too large for its in-memory object store. You can use [`ray memory`](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-core/objects/memory-management.html) to get a summary of how much of each storage Ray is using.

On Dask, modin [uses](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/blob/97769988a6f19e4b76f34238c97bf159ee7626a5/modin/core/execution/dask/common/engine_wrapper.py#L89) [`dask.Client.scatter`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.scatter), which also doesn't give guarantees about where the data will go, to store partition data. I don't know any way to figure out how much of the stored data is really in RAM.

Comment: thank you! i started reading stuff you linked, and now i start appreciating the depth of this rabbithole, if no one answers the question directly soon (which i believe is going to be the case) i will accept your answer as it shows the terrifying context of memory management complexities